# Custom blocks to display for students in moodle

Tags: moodle

I have created a custom block in moodle. The block displays perfectly on admin and manager account. But it doesnt display on the student account.
I have created db/access.php file. I have also created  tests/generator_test.php (copied as same from online_user block by changing the key names ). The block is not visible in site admistrator/users/permission/define roles/ student and then clicking on edit. (Block: online users        allow). The same is not showing for my block. 
Some one please help me with this. I want to display that block on students dashboard.

Answer (score 0):

If you have already installed the block then any changes to `db/access.php` won't apply until the version number is bumped.

So just increase the version number in `blocks/yourblock/version.php` then go to site admin -> notifications to update it.

If that doesn't work then show the contents of access.php.

Comment: Access.php  defined('MOODLE_INTERNAL') || die();

 

$capabilities = array(

 

    'block/courses_assigned:myaddinstance' => array(

        'captype' => 'write',

        'contextlevel' => CONTEXT_SYSTEM,

        'archetypes' => array(

            'user' => CAP_ALLOW

        ),

 

        'clonepermissionsfrom' => 'moodle/my:manageblocks'

    ),

 

       'block/courses_assigned:addinstance' => array(

        'riskbitmask' => RISK_SPAM | RISK_XSS,

 

        'captype' => 'write',

        'contextlevel' => CONTEXT_BLOCK,

        'archetypes' => array(

            'editingteacher' =

Comment: Now i am able to see the block courses_assigned in the permission column for students. I have given allow permisiion to it. But 1 more question to add a block on to student dashboard. I need to add that block somewhere to display it. How my block will be seen for the student profile. The access.php has not the full file as the editor doesnt allowed such big file. But i have copied from online_user block access.php file and changed the key name in it.